# Material UI Autocomplete - Disable listbox after the item selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating an Autocomplete component in React.js with the help of [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/) headless [useAutoComplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#useautocomplete) hook. The component is working properly. When the user tries to type any character, the `Listbox` will automatically open.

But the problem is that when the user selects anything and pays attention to the input element, the `ListBox` reopens. How can I prevent this?

**Codesandbox:**

[image: Edit fg56t]

**Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import useAutocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/useAutocomplete';

function AutocompleteComponent(props) {
  const { data } = props;

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = function () {
    if (value.length > 0) {
      setIsOpen(true);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = function (event, newInputValue) {
    setValue(newInputValue);
    if (newInputValue.length > 0) {
      setIsOpen(true);
    } else {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: 'form-control',
    options: data,
    autoComplete: true,
    open: isOpen, // Manually control
    onOpen: handleOpen, // Manually control
    onClose: () => setIsOpen(false), // Manually control
    inputValue: value, // Manually control
    onInputChange: handleInputChange, // Manually control
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.name
  });

  const listItem = {
    className: 'form-control__item'
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="form">
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Location"
            {...getInputProps()}
          />
        </div>
        {groupedOptions.length > 0 && (
          <ul
            className="form-control__box"
            aria-labelledby="autocompleteMenu"
            {...getListboxProps()}
          >
            {groupedOptions.map((option, index) => {
              return (
                <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })} {...listItem}>
                  <div>{option.name}</div>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AutocompleteComponent;
```

Comment: I just updated your code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fg56t-forked-g7pdp?file=/src/Autocomplete/index.js) code. Please review. Once the user selects some value, we're just disabling the input using below code.

`disabled={Boolean(value) && !isOpen}`

Although, this disables the ability to re-edit the selection, after the user has selected some value.

Comment: @Junaid The Autocomplete should not disable, the user can reenter any match results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the selectedItem in a state and use it in handleOpen to decide whether the list has to be displayed.
For setting selectedItem you can modify the default click provided by getOptionProps

```
import React from 'react';
import useAutocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/useAutocomplete';

function AutocompleteComponent(props) {
  const { data } = props;

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState('');

  const handleOpen = function () {
    if (value.length > 0 && selectedItem !== value) {
      setIsOpen(true);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = function (event, newInputValue) {
    setValue(newInputValue);
    if (newInputValue.length > 0) {
      setIsOpen(true);
    } else {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: 'form-control',
    options: data,
    autoComplete: true,
    open: isOpen, // Manually control
    onOpen: handleOpen, // Manually control
    onClose: () => setIsOpen(false), // Manually control
    inputValue: value, // Manually control
    onInputChange: handleInputChange, // Manually control
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.name
  });

  const listItem = {
    className: 'form-control__item'
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="form">
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Location"
            {...getInputProps()}
          />
        </div>
        {groupedOptions.length > 0 && (
          <ul
            className="form-control__box"
            aria-labelledby="autocompleteMenu"
            {...getListboxProps()}
          >
            {groupedOptions.map((option, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}
                  {...listItem}
                  onClick={(ev) => {
                    setSelectedItem(option.name);
                    getOptionProps({ option, index }).onClick(ev);
                  }}
                >
                  <div>{option.name}</div>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AutocompleteComponent;
```

[image: Edited]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the props passed to the inputbox, before applying them. That way you can delete the event that happens when the input is clicked.

```
var newProps = getInputProps();

delete newProps.onMouseDown; //delete the extra MouseDown event

return (
...
    <input
    ...
     
    placeholder="Location"
    {...newProps}  //use newProps rather than calling getInputProps
```

And it will stop showing that popup when you click it.

You can check the working code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fg56t-forked-fxqo7?file=/src/Autocomplete/index.js)